# MongoDB: retrieve only certain properties of a document after matching

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a MongoDB collection called `books`.

An example of a document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62bf10951fecaed4dba275b1"),
    "name" : "Library 1",
    "positions" : [ 
        {
            "number" : 2,
            "nodes" : [ 
                {
                    "number" : 2,
                    "bookId" : "6254674d3711f90bd8e76036"
                }, 
                {
                    "number" : 1,
                    "bookId" : "621e9b5aa7951d0be4516c18"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "number" : 1,
            "nodes" : [ 
                {
                    "number" : 1,
                    "bookId" : "6254674d3711f90bd8e76037"
                }, 
                {
                    "number" : 3,
                    "bookId" : "6254674d3711f90bd8e76039"
                }, 
                {
                    "number" : 2,
                    "bookId" : "6254674d3711f90bd8e76035"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to run a query that, based on a book ID, returns the `name`, the `positions.number` and the `positions.node.number`.

For example, if I search for the ID 6254674d3711f90bd8e76035, it should return:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("62bf10951fecaed4dba275b1"),
    name: "Library 1",
    positions: {
        number: 1,
        nodes: {
            number: 2
        }
    }
}
```

So far, this is what I came out with:

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([
    { $match: { "positions.nodes.bookId": "6254674d3711f90bd8e76035" } },
    { $project: { name: 1, "positions.number": 1, "positions.nodes.number": 1 } }
])
```

Unfortunately, this returns every single node. I might need something that says:
"Select name, position.number, position.nodes.number where bookId = 6254674d3711f90bd8e76035"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([
{
    $match: {"positions.nodes.books": "6254674d3711f90bd8e76035"}
},
{
    $unwind: "$positions"
},
{
    $unwind: "$positions.nodes"
},
{
    $match: {"positions.nodes.books": "6254674d3711f90bd8e76035"}
},
])
```